# Edge Detection with Thresholded Image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I'm trying to properly detect the edges of a playing card that has been blurred, grayscaled and then thresholded. I thought having the sharp black and white contrast would make the edges quite easy to detect, but no joy so far. I'm starting with:

[image]

And using the Canny Edge Detector I wrote producing this:

[image]

The result of Sobel was basically the same. However using OpenCV's Canny Detection I could produce this:

[image]

The border being correctly fitted together is what I'm desperately needing to recreate in my own code, and I'm not committed to using any particular type of Edge Detection, I just need to find an algorithm that will give me the connected edge! My Canny code can be found [here](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3506), and it is very much based from the LIRE code [here.](https://code.google.com/p/lire/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/net/semanticmetadata/lire/imageanalysis/filters/CannyEdgeDetector.java) If anybody could help me go from the first image to the third I would be incredibly grateful! Any edge detection welcome!

Edit: Code for NMS:

```
    //main program
    for(int x = 1; x < width-1; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 1; y < height-1; y++)
        {
            if(src.getRaster().getPixel(x, y, tmp)[0] >= 250)
            {
                trackWeakOnes(x, y, src);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void trackWeakOnes(int x, int y, BufferedImage src) 
    {
        for (int a = x - 1; a <= x + 1; a++)
        {
            for (int b = y - 1; b <= y + 1; b++) 
            {
                if (checkWeak(a, b, src)) 
                {
                    src.getRaster().setPixel(x, y, tmpMax);
                    trackWeakOnes(a, b, src);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkWeak(int x, int y, BufferedImage src)
    {   
        return ((src.getRaster().getPixel(x, y, tmpPix)[0] > 0) && 
                (src.getRaster().getPixel(x, y, tmpPix)[0] < 255));
    }
```

tmpPix is an empty array to be filled, tmpMax is an array {255, 255, 255} to make edges white.

Comment: I don't get the point of your question. Would you please clarify what you are looking for exactly?

Comment: Write my own edge detection that can detect the edges in the first image so it looks like the third image, as apposed to the broken edges in the second one. The one I've written doesn't detect the border of the card properly. I'm not committed to using only Canny, I'll try other edge detection algorithms if they work!

Comment: Why don't you just use the OpenCV Canny if that works?

Comment: Doing this as part of a uni project, identifying playing card suit/rank. Need to write my own edge detection, but have had very little luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this clean image, you don't need complex algorithms.  A couple of simple filters will do the trick.

In matlab, the code looks like:

```
O=abs(filter2([-1 0 1],I))+abs(filter2([-1;0;1],I));
```

which means that for each pixel  (x,y) you do:

```
output(x,y) = abs( I(x+1,y)-I(x-1,y) ) + abs( I(x,y+1) - I(x,y-1) );
```

Comment: So just get the absolute values of the difference in pixel value above/below and left/right of the pixel in question? I'll try this in a sec.

Comment: So this was the output: http://imgur.com/phvWPjO ? Any suggestion for where to tinker it?

Comment: This is not the output I get.  You're probably getting problems when working with pixels as unsigned integers in the range of 0-255.   Try to convert to floating point and normalize pixels to 0-1, and it should look better.

Comment: The input you're getting is a properly detected edge? I'm working BufferedImage in Java and working with doubles. If they exceed 255 I just set them to 255. Is that not the same process? Sorry but I'm not sure of the process of normalising pixels as 0-1. Would that just be dividing the initial value by 255 and then multiplying the result by 255 at the end?

Comment: Yes, I divide by 255 to get the 0-1.   Make sure you're not filtering the image in place.  Since each pixel's output value depends on its neighbors, you have to write the output to a different image.

Comment: Oh wow that's a fantastic point, I'm editing the source image like a fool. Once again I'll give it a go!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read your code, but I observe a strange artifact: along the horizontal edges, the detected pixels come in isolated 8-connected triples. I would suspect a flaw in the non-maximum suppression logics. (In any case, there is an anisotropy somewhere.)

This said, edge detection on a binary image can be done by [contour tracing](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/index.html).

Comment: I suspected the same thing given how similar the Sobel and Canny outputs were. Is there a particular contour tracing algorithm you'd recommend? Edit: I'll add my code for non-maximum suppression in the original question so you don't have to search.

Comment: My favorite is the radial sweep, but all these algorithms are about the same. They require great care for the starting and ending conditions. You could be interested by the related article "Digital Topology, Azriel Rosenfeld, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 86, No. 8. (Oct., 1979), pp. 621-630." Old, but still true :)